# using restsharp for JWT for JSON parsing to object doesn't work

Tags: json, jwt, restsharp

I'm using Restsharp to do RestApi and using JWT auth. The code is simple like this. I think it the response content will be deserialized to my object type(AccessTokenInfo), but it didn't work.

```
log is "token=, expire=0"
```

Is there something I lost? BTW, I log the response.ContentType is "application/json;charset=UTF-8", is it not compatibility to RestSharp?

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
client.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(jwt);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST);
client.ExecuteAsync<AccessTokenInfo>(request, response => {
   Console.WriteLine("token={0}, expire={1}",response.Data.token, response.Data.expiresIn);
});
```

the response content like this: `"token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHBp_1imaCD7ovhZAbS6iUQ","expiresIn":43199`

Comment: I have found the problem, it because my own object type(AccessTokenInfo) don't use property.
    public class JWTAccessTokenInfo
    {
        public string token;
        public UInt64 expiresIn;
    }
change to following, it work, but why?
    public class JWTAccessTokenInfo
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public UInt64 expiresIn { get; set; }
    }

Comment: That's just how RestSharp's deserializer works -- they use reflection to find all public properties to bind to, which means they won't see fields. This is very common (lots of binding/seralizing/etc systems work this way). There's often Attributes you can use to force the system to see your field but it's better to just use properties.